# Google +1 integration: Yea or nae?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Google just rolled out it's +1 feature across the web, and it got me thinking that using it on SE sites could be a great way to further promote great questions since the more a site or page gets +1 clicks the higher it appears in Google's search results.

Good idea?  Bad idea?  Redundant idea?

Discuss.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/any-plans-supporting-google-for-link-sharing-in-the-near-future

Answer (score 9):

> Since the more a site or page gets +1 clicks the higher it appears in Google's search results

Er.. this isn't true, and if it was there would be, as Robocop once said, "problems".

These +1s are intimately tied to Social Search, that is, if Google knows who you are and your friend network, those results might be escalated *for you only*:

http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=1067707

Comment: The correction is much appreciated.  I read Google's blog post about it pretty quickly.  Also, if I could upvote you twice I would because of the Robocop reference.

Comment: OT: "Come quietly or there will be... **trouble**."

Answer (score 6):

I'll never use +1, just like I never use StumbleUpon or the Facebook "likes".  That said, other people will.  I see no reason not too, really.  Even if it dies in the future, it's probably not much work to integrate it (the SE people or Al can correct me on this if I'm wrong).

Comment: I'm not much of a 'liker', but I liked your post.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I've installed it on my own site.

I've also got the Chrome extension to be able to use it anywhere.

I think it could easily go with the Facebook and Twitter links we have already.

Comment: That Chrome extension is great.

Comment: What chrome extension?

Comment: @t0mm13b: I use this one: [Google +1 button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-%201-button/jgoepmocgafhnchmokaimcmlojpnlkhp)

Comment: @AlEverett cheers mate for that :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm all for it. In fact, I;d say add more sites like Reddit / Ping.fm etc. The more a question / solution can be shared or publicised, the better it is, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely vote yes. G+ is growing rapidly, and the community is strongly tied to this one, many G+ users being Google enthusiasts already, and many having strong ties to Android as well. I think it'd be a good idea to jump on this boat early.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm also not the kind of guy to "Like" or +1 sth, I'd +1 the idea of integrating +1.